# Marshalling int* to C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I've a function in C++ `void someFunc(char* arg1, int* arg2)` which I want to marshal the parameters as I use this function in C# (after importing the DLL)..

Can you pls tell me how I should marshall as I'm confused here.

```
[DllImport(Dllname)]
extern void someFunc([MarshallAsAttribute(UnmanagedType,LPStr)] string arg1, IntPtr arg2);
```

Should I use an IntPtr here? I cant pass the address of any int variable from C# so that it would land up in the pointer in C++?

Comment: You can actually use native pointers in C#, using unsafe code blocks. Though I wouldn't recommend it, as it leads for an unintuitive API.

Comment: You'll need to describe the meaning of those pointers. In particular how much data they point too, if the function keeps the pointers after it returns, and if you want to pass `null` to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is `int*` can be used for a lot of different scenarios in C.  How you marshal this depends a bit on what the `int* arg2` is meant to represent.

For example, if it's just setting a value of an int, you can marshal this as `ref int`.  However, if the `int*` is representing an array, you'll want to pass an array (this is unlikely, however, as there is no length term, which is common when using an array via a pointer).

Comment: And a `char*` is even more ambiguous.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yes - any pointer type has this issue.  You always need to know what the native side is planning to do with this variable.